# Angular version 13 issue with Safari version 16.2 `<app-root></app-root>` element is empty

Tags: angular, macos, safari

My angular application which version 13 is not rendering in safari 16.2. I dont see any error in console.

While inspecting the rendered dom I can see `<app-root></app-root>` element is empty. I have polyfills enabled in tsconfig.

has anyone have the same issue or any solution for this issue ?

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue

Comment: I got it resolved. It was happening because of regex related to 'lookbehind' 'lookahead'.  regex 'lookbehind' and 'lookahead' is not supported in safari so replaced the regex and that fixed the issue.